# What is the best ordering of purchases when you have a 10% voucher on everything you buy?

Tags: algorithm, haskell

A shop is giving out a voucher on every purchase, which can be used towards your next purchase. The value of the voucher is 10% of your current purchase. For example, on a $10 purchase, you receive a $1 voucher towards your next purchase.

You need to buy *n* things. In what order should you pay them in order to spend as little money as possible?

So, if the prices of the articles are *u*<sub>0</sub>, *u*<sub>1</sub>, ... *u*<sub>*n*-1</sub>, then the prices you will actually pay will be *v*<sub>0</sub>, ... *v*<sub>*n*-1</sub>, with the recurrence rule *v*<sub>*k*+1</sub> = max(0, *u*<sub>*k*+1</sub> - *α* × *v*<sub>*k*</sub>), *v*<sub>0</sub> = *u*<sub>0</sub>, and in this case, *α* = 10/100.

Example:

> You need to buy 3 articles, which cost respectively $1, $10 and $100.
>     Then you should buy them in the following order: $1, $100, $10
>
> Thus, you will pay
>
> `1 + (100 - 1 * 10%) + (10 - (100 - 1 * 10%) * 10%) = 1 + 99.9 + 0.01 = 100.91`
>
> This is better than you would do with any other ordering.

(Of course, if at one point you happen to have a reduction higher then the price of the next article
you want to buy, the shop doesn't give you money. You can only pay positive amounts of money)

I [implemented a naive algorithm](https://gist.github.com/lovasoa/db6d42bcae40a59d474699588ea08e97) that solves this problem in factorial time, but cannot find a general algorithm that would solve this problem in reasonable time.

Comment: Can you clarify the algorithm for calculating the final price? I understood this as _p0_+max(_p1_-_a1_,0)+max(_p2_-_a2_,0)+...+max(_pn_-_an_,0) where p0,...,pn are the base prices and ai := 0.1*(p(n-1)-a(n-1)).

Comment: That's it. I'll update the question.

Comment: Also, are you sure an efficient algorithm exists? The problem is obviously in NP (or rather, the decision version is), but it sounds vaguely similar to some NPC problems so there's a chance it might not be efficiently solvable. Would be another story of course if this was a homework question and you were already told an efficient algorithm exists.

Comment: I'm actually not sure an efficient algorithm exists. But I really think so. In fact, if you remove the rule of no negative amounts, a simple solution exists: you order the article such that the last one will be the less expensive, the one before the most expensive, the one before the second less expensive, the one before the second most expensive, etc...

Comment: Of course. I just changed it, thank you.